Is there philosophy for uncertainty and fear?
I always have thoughts that I might burn in hell from God. I can’t find a reason to believe in Him but there are certain coincidences that I have seen in the world and in my life that are hard to explain without God. This leads to a lot of uncertainty and confusion since I am unsure of what will happen to me after I die. I can see arguments from both sides. I lean more towards the godless side if a gun was put to my head but I’m unsure.
Can philosophy or anything in philosophy help me?

Schopenhauer’s tranquillity amidst irrational violent world his philosophy paints is one option. Refuge in art, especially music, distancing from the world to reach a peaceful state of mind. He was a fan of PSR, btw. Nietzsche's "we only have art so as not to die before the truth" was inspired by Schopenhauer. Stoicism, with its message of curbing passions by reason, structured life and perseverance in the face of hardship, is another option.

You could have faith that you will eventually see and understand. Something like the Serenity Prayer. It worked for me. Buddhists and Nonduality teachers say that enlightenment is inevitable if you work at it.

My input :- just like what Scott Rowe and Conifold have mentioned are really great and I believe anyone would benefit from both paths but understanding theology through the lens of philosophy (especially metaphysics and ontology) and further diving into a belief system and learning about it is something that might help. Also, God will not let a trusting creation burn, forgiveness and redemption actually work especially if one reflects and look upon one's actions and commits to change.

Have you seen A course in miracles?

@Rushi I know this is kind of left field but what are your thoughts on Deepak Chopra?

Non trivial question @Howwhye!! DC was good some 20 odd years ago then he went overboard into his cult. But behind the nonsense you will still find gems. Eg. here Do you, Sir, believe in the infinite? Note: You can only believe in the infinite. You cannot know/think/understand/grok the infinite. In that one line DC knocks out the theoretical physicist. But for the most part he just makes a fool of himself.  So in short a mixed bag I'd say. If you want something more sane n balanced but still inspiring in that direction I'd recommend Ravi Ravindra

@Rushi I am ambivalent on His stance as well. I will say this humans are funny including myself, we tend to grasp things that are truly phenomenal, wise or profound yet when faced with matters of societal recognition/fame or money (the force is palpable), it seems like we forget the profoundness of our outlooks and understanding completely or feel the need to maintain or intermingle it so that it works with whatever seems to work. (syncretize) The dichotomy of humans is what happened to DC which is the norm. I wish we could overcome our shortsightedness in some way,

@Howwhye Or more mainstream and v good: Eckhart Tolle, Thich Nhat Hahn........ Above mesg crossed while I sent mine. All ill say is meditation is necessary.  For everyone

@Rushi Well for me I think prayer is necessary for everyone, but one can agree prayer (intentional prayer) to a creator is the greatest form of meditation one can possibly do. Through prayer one learns humility and togetherness with all that has been created under the creator.

@Howwhye Why distinguish? Ravi Ravindra (i mentioned above) who has taught meditation for many decades, often starts his guided sitting practice with this: We take a posture of meditation and an attitude of prayer.

@Rushi I can see your point but the distinguish here is the remembrance and direction of prayer towards the Creator instead of inwards (self) and to the creation itself.

The inside and the outside need to match.


I always have thoughts that I might burn in hell from God.

Baruch Spinoza describes an affect as a feeling of desire, pleasure, or pain accompanied by an idea of its cause. He describes love as a feeling of pleasure, and hatred as a feeling of pain, each accompanied by an idea of its external cause. He describes hope as inconstant pleasure and fear as inconstant pain. In this context the fear of hell is inconstant pain generated in the present and accompanied by an idea of its external cause.
Anxiety is the word for pain in the present accompanied by the anticipation (fear) of further pain, disability, or death in the future. The book How to Stop Worrying and Start Living gives this advice: live in day-tight compartments. Pleasure in the present, and accurate ideas about the causes of our feelings, gives us the strength to eliminate the pain in the present that can be attenuated with self-help or other-help. Pleasure in the present is the only means to attenuate pain that cannot be attenuated by the actions of self or others. Hope means we plan for pleasure now and in the future even if we also feel anxiety and fear too.

I don't know if reading (about) philosophy can help with actual, direct extential feelings of anxiety about punishments after death. It's hard to argue against ingrained feelings.

there are certain coincidences that I have seen in the world and in my life that are hard to explain without God. This leads to a lot of uncertainty

One thing that you could consider is that there is much more randomness in the world than you may think - a coincidence can be just that. You could also ask yourself, whether or not a god would really explain the coincidences that you experienced. For instance, if the coincidence involved some "miraculous" rescue - then what about all those other people that were not rescued in similar circumstances? Are you really that different from those people? If not, wouldn't you then have to admit that the divine is either capricious or cruel? And can you believe in a capricious, irrational, cruel god?
Rather than just reading philosophical arguments, you might find it more interesting (and beneficial) to read autobiographies of some philosophers (like Bertrand Russel's) or novels with a strong philosophical background (like Albert Camus' The Pest). When you're looking for a new philosophy of life - or searching to escape from a stifling philosophy of life -, it's not just pure rational or rationalistic arguments that count.
